# CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW is not working on macOS Mojave

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql, materialized-views

I am trying to create a Materialized View on a query via psql. When I execute `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` I get no feedback from the terminal, and the command doesn't hang. However, running any further queries give no results:

```
pop=# select * from products;
 id |    name     |           createdAt           | price | categoryId | makerId 
----+-------------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+---------
  1 | Shampoo     | 2021-08-13 10:05:32.36197+10  |    20 |          3 | A
  2 | Conditioner | 2021-08-13 10:05:32.364625+10 |  10.5 |          3 | A
(2 rows)

pop=# CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW search_index AS 
SELECT products.id,
       products.name,
       setweight(to_tsvector(products.name), 'A') || 
       setweight(to_tsvector(categories.name), 'C') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(makers.name), 'B') ||
       setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(string_agg(tags.name, ' '))), 'A') as document
FROM products
JOIN categories ON categories.id = products."categoryId"
JOIN makers ON makers.id = products."makerId"
JOIN "productsTags" ON "productsTags"."productId" = "productsTags"."tagId"
JOIN tags ON tags.id = "productsTags"."tagId"
GROUP BY products.id, categories.id, makers.id;

pop(# select * from products;
pop(# select version();
pop(# \dm
Did not find any relations.
pop(# 
\q
```

If I re-launch into psql queries work again. I'm wondering how I can debug this problem? Running PostgreSQL and psql 13.3 installed via Homebrew, macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: why prompt is different? "pop=#" vs "pop(#"

Comment: Omg, `postgres(# indicates you have an open parenthesis`, I must have not closed my parentheses, thank you @mangusta.